# How to prove that the recursive definition is correct?

Tags: calculus, recursion

The recursive definition of the set of positive integers that are exponentiations of $3$ is:

1) $b_0=1$

2) $b_n=3(b_{n-1})$ for $n\ge 1$

Is it correct?

Now how can I prove that this definition is correct?

Comment: What mathematical definition of that set are you starting with? I'll just point out that the sentence "the set of positive integers that are exponentiations of $3$" is a nice intuitive explanation of the set, but it is *not* a mathematical definition.

Comment: To prove this "definition" is correct means to show it is equivalent to another way of defining the "exponentiations of 3".  So to begin you need to write down that definition.   Then the proof consists of showing the two sets so defined are equal.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to prove
$$
b_n = 3^n \quad (n \in \mathbb{N})
$$
Induction seems natural to prove this.

But let us try something more fun. There is also a solution from the theory of [linear recurrences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients):

The characteristic polynomial of the linear homogeneous recurrence with constant coefficients
$$
b_n = 3 b_{n-1}
$$
is
$$
p(t) = t - 3
$$
with root $r=3$ and general solution
$$
b_n = k \, 3^n
$$
We derive the constant $k$ from the initial condition
$$
b_0 = 1
$$
thus
$$
1 = k \, 3^0
$$
which gives $k=1$ and the solution $b_n = 3^n$.

Answer (score 1):

You may try Mathematical induction to show that $b_n = 3^n$

For $n=0,$ the statement is $b_0 = 3^0 =1 $ which is true.

If the statement if true for $n$ , then $$ b_{n+1} = 3 b_n = 3(3^n)=3^{n+1}$$

Thus the statement is true for all $n\ge 0$